# Can't connect remotely to MariaDB with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, linux, raspberry-pi, mariadb

I'm using a Raspberry Pi as a weather station and we are trying to connect it to a remote Linux server as the web server. We are running MariaDB as the MySQL database and the data is currently going smoothly from the sensors to the database. Unfortunately, we have been trying everything to connect our web server to our database.

**This is the error we are receiving:** "Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.x.xxx' (110)"

Port 3306 is opened on the router it is behind.

The only config file that I have been able to find that actually includes the bind-address line that I commented out was located here: /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf

When I run "sudo netstat -ntlup | grep mysql". **This is returned:**

```
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      4481/mysqld
```

**This is the 50-server.cnf file below:**

```
# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see
#
# See the examples of server my.cnf files in /usr/share/mysql/
#

# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]

#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address       = 127.0.0.1

#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size     = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam_recover_options  = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10

#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M

#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Enable the slow query log to see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log_file    = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
#long_query_time = 10
#log_slow_rate_limit    = 1000
#log_slow_verbosity = query_plan
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = exclude_database_name

#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!

#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates you can use for example the GUI tool "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
#
# Accept only connections using the latest and most secure TLS protocol version.
# ..when MariaDB is compiled with OpenSSL:
# ssl-cipher=TLSv1.2
# ..when MariaDB is compiled with YaSSL (default in Debian):
# ssl=on

#
# * Character sets
#
# MySQL/MariaDB default is Latin1, but in Debian we rather default to the full
# utf8 4-byte character set. See also client.cnf
#
character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci

#
# * Unix socket authentication plugin is built-in since 10.0.22-6
#
# Needed so the root database user can authenticate without a password but
# only when running as the unix root user.
#
# Also available for other users if required.
# See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/unix_socket-authentication-plugin/

# this is only for embedded server
[embedded]

# This group is only read by MariaDB servers, not by MySQL.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MySQL and MariaDB,
# you can put MariaDB-only options here
[mariadb]

# This group is only read by MariaDB-10.1 servers.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MariaDB of different versions,
# use this group for options that older servers don't understand
[mariadb-10.1]
```

**This is the PHP file I am using to test the connection:**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("192.168.x.xxx","team","password","Weather");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="SELECT * FROM WeatherData2";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

// Numeric array
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
printf ("%s (%s)\n",$row[1],$row[2], $row[3]);

// Associative array
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf ("%s (%s)\n",$row["Date"],$row["Time"], $row["Temperature"]);

// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: In the mysql config, `#bind-address       = 127.0.0.1` should be uncommented and set to the public IP of the machine it's running on.

Comment: Or even better, set to ```bind-address = 0.0.0.0 ```. It will work for local and remote connections.

Comment: What `GRANT` do you have?